# How to update a table with a recursive CTE?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I hope you can help me

I have a problem over here, been trying to solve this but cannot figure out how. I have a simple table which represents reps and their leaders over cycles (time measures) like this:
RepID|LeaderID|CycleID

I need to calculate for each leader the whole tree below them only with certain status twice, because the formula is:
(All reps below the leader with status 1 or 2) - (All reps below the leader on the previous cycle with status 7)

My code is as follows:

```
update ccp
set ccp.Total_reps = 
(
    select isnull(COUNT(*),0)       
    from dbo.MCP_Reps_by_cycle ccp_total_reps
    join dbo.MCP_Compensation_Plan cp_total_reps on cp_total_reps.ID_Compensation_Plan = ccp_total_reps.ID_Compensation_Plan and cp_total_reps.CycleID = @previous_cycle and cp_total_reps.Definitive = 1 and cp_total_reps.Active = 1
    join dbo.F_Get_reps(ccp.RepID, @previous_cycle) r on r.RepID = ccp_total_reps.RepID
    where ccp_total_reps.StatusDetailID in(1,2) and ccp_total_reps.Active = 1
)
-
(
    select isnull(COUNT(*),0)
    from dbo.MCP_Reps_by_cycle ccp_total_reps       
    join dbo.MCP_Compensation_Plan cp_total_reps on cp_total_reps.ID_Compensation_Plan = ccp_total_reps.ID_Compensation_Plan and cp_total_reps.CycleID = @previous_cycle_two and cp_total_reps.Definitive = 1 and cp_total_reps.Active = 1
    join dbo.F_Get_reps(ccp.RepID, @previous_cycle_two) r on r.RepID = ccp_total_reps.RepID
    where ccp_total_reps.StatusDetailID = 7 and ccp_total_reps.Active = 1
)
from dbo.MCP_Reps_by_cycle ccp  
join dbo.MCP_Compensation_Plan cp on cp.ID_Compensation_Plan = ccp.ID_Compensation_Plan and cp.ID_Compensation_Plan = @ID_Compensation_Plan and cp.Active = 1
where ccp.Active = 1
```

What the F_Get_reps function does, is a simple recursive CTE:

```
RETURNS @MIT table (RepID int)
as
begin

    with rep_network as (
        select ccp.RepID
        from dbo.MCP_Reps_by_cycle ccp
        join dbo.MCP_Compensation_Plan cp on cp.ID_Compensation_Plan = ccp.ID_Compensation_Plan and cp.CycleID = @cycleid and cp.Definitive = 1 and cp.Active = 1
        where ccp.Active = 1 and ccp.LeaderID = @repid
        union all
        select ccp_2.RepID
        from dbo.MCP_Reps_by_cycle ccp_2
        join dbo.MCP_Compensation_Plan cp_2 on cp_2.ID_Compensation_Plan = ccp_2.ID_Compensation_Plan and cp_2.CycleID = @cycleid and cp_2.Definitive = 1 and cp_2.Active = 1
        join rep_network r on r.RepID = ccp_2.LeaderID
        where ccp_2.Active = 1
    )

    insert into @MIT
    select RepID
    from rep_network

    return
end
```

I know the call to the function is the problem, but I cannot figure out how to remove it.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might lessen the problem with the function call if you convert your multi-statement TVF into an inline TVF. (DROP the multi-statement version, then CREATE the inline one under the same name. ALTER won't work.) On a different note, you don't need to apply ISNULL to COUNT, because COUNT never returns a NULL.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure, from your wording, if you have any problem with the results or just with the performance of your query. Could you clarify that?

Comment: Is just the performance issue, can you please clarify tour previous suggestion? I'm afraid I didnt understand it. Thanks!!